Preventing refresh after using the click() function on an anchor element
I'm trying to implement a download button in my web application that allows users to download a JSON file without refreshing the page. The download is triggered via Javascript.
button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const json = {a:"abc", d:"def"};
        const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(json)], { type: 'application/json' });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var download = document.createElement('a');
        download.href = url;
        download.download = "test.json";
        download.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    });

Despite using event.preventDefault(), the page still refreshes when the button is clicked. I suspect that I need to prevent the default behavior of the click() method on the anchor element, not the button element, but I'm unsure how to achieve this.

What is the "button" element? It might help to add your HTML to make a working example that demonstrates the issue.

I had the same exact issue today,but then i figured out it was LiveServer refreshing my page everytime something changed inside my download folder,are you also perhaps using LiveServer?

I feel so silly, it was in fact LiveServer.
